# SQL Server 2016 - Variable showing NULL

Tags: sql-server-2016

We have a scalar function in our application as below

```
CREATE function dbo.SCMGetEnvProfileValueFn
    (@HierarchyCode  varchar(255),    -- Usually the subsystem code
     @Code  varchar(50),              -- The Code to find
     @Default varchar(255)            -- If not found, return this default
    )
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Value as varchar(255)

    SELECT @Value = (SELECT TOP(1) Value FROM HVCEnvProfile
                     WHERE HierarchyCode = @HierarchyCode 
                       AND Code = @Code)

    RETURN ISNULL (@Value, @Default)
END
```

We converted this function to Table function

```
CREATE FUNCTION SCMGetEnvProfileValueTblFn
    (@HierarchyCode  varchar(255),    -- Usually the subsystem code
     @Code varchar(50),              -- The Code to find
     @Default varchar(255)            -- If not found, return this default
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        (SELECT TOP(1) ISNULL (Value, @Default) AS value 
         FROM HVCEnvProfile
         WHERE HierarchyCode = @HierarchyCode AND Code = @Code)
```

Below 2 statements shows different output. We do not have a column in the table HVCEnvProfile for this entry. Why the variable @Value is showing NULL when there is no row in the table.

```
SELECT value 
FROM dbo.SCMGetEnvProfileValueTblFn('Registration', 'AdmitDtmEffectsLocationHistory', 'TRUE')

SELECT dbo.SCMGetEnvProfileValueFn('Registration', 'AdmitDtmEffectsLocationHistory', 'TRUE')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a query returns no rows, then no rows will be returned, wrapping an `ISNULL` won't change that. Example:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(V.C,0)
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4))V(C)
WHERE V.C = 5;
```

Notice this does *not* return `0`, but nothing.

You need to wrap the entire query in an `ISNULL`.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION SCMGetEnvProfileValueTblFn (@HierarchyCode varchar(255), -- Usually the subsystem code
                                            @Code varchar(50),           -- The Code to find
                                            @Default varchar(255)        -- If not found, return this default
)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN
    SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP (1) [Value]
                   FROM HVCEnvProfile
                   WHERE HierarchyCode = @HierarchyCode
                     AND Code = @Code
                     ORDER BY SomeColumn), @Default) AS [Value]; --Don' forgot to change the value of SomeColumn
```

Don't forget, as well, you need an `ORDER BY` when using a `TOP` unless you're "happy" with inconsistent results (which I doubt), so i have added one that you will need to amend.

Comment: If it worked, please consider marking the answer as the solution, @omkar, so that future readers know the answer was helpful. I also suggest doing this on other questions you have asked, as it appears you have [never accepted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255079/omkar?tab=questions) as the solution.

Comment: So why  the @value showing NULL in the scalar function?

Comment: `@value` will be `NULL` if no returns are returned, in the scalar function, as when **subquery** that would normally return a scalar value returns no rows, it is treated as returning `NULL`. Example `SELECT (SELECT 1 WHERE 2 = 3) AS SQ;`